# Why my mongoose objectId request return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I past my day to find the answer, in vain.

**this is my mongoose schema:**

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value: {type: String},
    title: {type: String},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    packId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Pack'}
});
```

**this is my request:**

*( Where packId is a ObjectId )*

```
var getElements = function(packId, callback ){
    Card.find(
        {packId: packId},
        function(err,els){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log(els);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

**And this is a table element **

```
{
    "title" : "test1",
    "value" : "test1",
    "packId" : ObjectId("54f9ebaae312727c45b2a80e"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f9ebaae312727c45b2a820"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-03-06T18:02:18.544Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I don't understand why the console.log(els) return [], because there is elements in table. I've tried whith {type: Sting} but nothing at all.

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you console.log(packId) ?

Comment: When i console.log(packId) i have 54f9ebaae312727c45b2a80e. And when i console.log(typeof packId) i have object

Comment: And when you query db.cards.find({packId: ObjectId('54f9ebaae312727c45b2a80e')}) in mongo shell what do you get?

Comment: I can read the result i need

Comment: Try starting your app with  `DEBUG=mquery node server.js`. Look and see what the actual query is. Mongoose might be acting stupid. as usual.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand your last comment. How and where can i use DEBUG=query

Comment: When you start your node server, start it with a `DEBUG` environment variable. `mquery` is mongo's debug value. You can look at your terminal and see the printed out queries.

Comment: Ok, i saw something strange :  mquery find +19ms { packId: 54f9fb4d61c171fc4d722421 } { fields: undefined } ... i have trouble with my fields ?

Comment: No, I get the same thing: `{ region: 'us-east-1', _id: 54f8ec4bd4f65c26c2ca5f3a } { fields: undefined }` I can also see that since 54f9fb4d61c171fc4d722421 doesn't have quotes it's sending an ObjectId.

Comment: and as an example of when an id is supposed to be a string: `findOne +20.3m { isGuest: true, 'devices.id': '12345abcde' } { fields: undefined }`

Comment: by the way, it looks like 54f9ebaae312727c45b2a80e and 54f9fb4d61c171fc4d722421 are different

Comment: yes, i reset the table

Comment: It's obviously querying the right packId, The only thing I can think of is that it's not querying the right collection of the right database. Try querying just an empty object and see what is returned: `Card.find({}, function(err, docs) {console.log(err, docs)})`

Comment: Done, same problem ... i'm loosing my religion ... i've tried with {type: string} with packId.toString() ... same ... But this is working for other tables !

Comment: So we know 3 things: 1: your collection isn't empty. 2: the query is not erroring out. 3: a query for all(`{}`) returns nothing. This tells me that you aren't connecting to the right db or collection. There is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: As commented your either connecting to the wrong database or more likely you are making the common mistake because your collection is actually called "card" and not "cards" as mongoose expects.  Correct with `mongoose.model( "Card", cardschema, "card" )` where the actual collection name is the third argument. Using that optional argument overrides what mongoose chooses as a default.

Comment: i'm connecting to the right database, because if i put a static val in my query like {packId: "54fb025077fcf9231939dd0e"}, it works ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i've found the reason.

```
models.Card.saveCards(completeData.cards,packData.cid, function(){
    models.Card.getCards(packData.cid,function(cards){
    ...
    }
}
```

the second method getCards is called before all cards are saved.

So this is how i did

```
    var saveCards = function( cardsData, packId, callback ){
        var nbCards = cardsData.length;
        var start = 0;

        var saveCard = function(cardData,packId) {
        cardData.packId = packId;
        var card = new Card(cardData);
        card.save(function (err, card) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if(start<nbCards-1){
                    start++;
                    saveCard(cardsData[start],packId);
                }else{
                    callback();
                }
            }
        });
    };

    if( start === 0){
        saveCard(cardsData[start],packId);
    }
};
```

hope this helps